# How can I implement a kafka streams retry for a error handler using a state store?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In a scenario where one would want to do retry on deserialization errors (or any kind of error for that matter), how would it be possible to link a state store to the deserialization error handler, so that we could store the offending event and later reprocess it?

I've tried to link a state store to the processorContext in the handler, with no success.

This is based on the suggestion made by @matthias-j-sax here: [Kafka Streams - Retrying a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186470/kafka-streams-retrying-a-message/75363550#75363550)

Additionally, once we do have the event on a state store and we're able to later fetch it using a punctuation, what would a retry mean? Stream it into the initial source topic once again?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll answer my own question here... looks like the only possible way is to forward the error message to a child processor and do the additional error processing there.

Potentially store it into a key/value state store and then with a scheduler implement the retry logic.

As for the actual retry, it gets a bit tricky, because if we're doing windowed aggregation with a custom timestamp extractor, we don't want to drop the retried event on the topic with a time that pre-dates the stream time as it will surely be dropped. So it looks like the timestamp needs to be modified before the retry.

Comment: Hi Bruno, it's a good idea if you can catch the exception and flag somehow your message.
and you could then use a branch in your kafka-stream to separate good from error messages ;) . Also, there is a schedular in kafka-streams called punctuator. please feel free to share if you have any pb with your test case ^^

Comment: @ahmed.ettoumi - but there's no way of catching a deserialization exception this way right? As it needs to happen on the handler. The handler has access to a processor context, but as the handler itself has no Child nodes, I can't forward the event to a processor to store it in state store. I also can't attach a state store to the handler, so not sure how to go about implementing a retry logic for failed deserialization.

Comment: deserialization exception happen only on consumer => this is could be handled, but out of the topology, so there is no way to redirect it to any processor node.
But the 'DeserializationExceptionHandler' has 3 implementation: LogAndContinueExceptionHandler, LogAndFailExceptionHandler AND DeadLetterTopicDeserializationExceptionHandler. The last one allow you to write errors on DLQ Topic => so you have the possibility to replay those messages by integrating your DLQ topic on source node, or Materialize this topic as a state-store on your kafka-stream if it's really needed on your use case.

Comment: Thanks @ahmed.ettoumi, the DeadLetterTopicDeserializationExceptionHandler might be helpful, I'll definitely try that. I also wanted to be able to inject dependencies into the handler, but I found a workaround for that by being able to extend the StreamConfig object.